# How to output in html a json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am running the following

**js**

```
  jQuery.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Infobox&eilimit=5&callback=?", {
    disablelimitreport: true,
    format: "json"
  }, function(data) {
    jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
            console.log(data);
            jQuery("#results").append("<li>" + data + "</li>");
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="results">

</ul>
```

**Output**

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

**Console.log:**

> Object {warnings: Object, batchcomplete: "", continue: Object, query:
>   Object}

What I am trying to do is to get all `html` content on those `json` results, and be able to find for each of the results a `div` with class `infobox` and strip everything but that content in that div and output it in my `html` list.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/21/)

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Infobox&eilimit=5

Basically `wikipedia api` has much going on, I am looking at finding all the pages, all of them, which has the infobox on the side, and be able to output the html in the list so that I can do a js parsing aftwards, see this https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xmlfm&titles=Scary%20Monsters%20and%20Nice%20Sprites&rvsection=0

Comment: If you want to append a list item for each object in the response, why are you using `data` to construct your HTML instead of `item`? This is really basic debugging.

Comment: @mason trying to learn and understand, that above is my try out and effort :)

Comment: So append the correct thing. And `item` is going to be a complex object. You need to decide what property of that you want to include in your HTML.

Comment: how do i know which `item` property I need to find the div with class property `infobox`?

Comment: @mason by looking at the object in console, i can see the title and page id, not its content so i cannot find the class i am looking for and its data

Comment: I don't know what you're even talking about. There's no div anywhere in the code you've provided. Wikipedia's API returns a complex JSON object. jQuery converts that to a JavaScript object. You need to determine which properties you want to display on your page and grab them. It's very straightforward.

Comment: Can you write down a sample of your desired output ? Which attribute of the response you want to print between `<li>` ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay wikipedia api has much going on, I am looking at finding all the pages, all of them, which has the infobox on the side, and be able to output the html in the list so that I can do a js parsing aftwards, see this https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xmlfm&titles=Scary%20Monsters%20and%20Nice%20Sprites&rvsection=0

Comment: you'll get some light bulb experience when you do `"<li>" + JSON.stringify(item) + "</li>"`

Comment: There is no content property in the response you're receiving from the API. You will probably have to make a separate API call to retrieve the content, or change how you're calling their API in the first place. I'm not familiar with their API.

Comment: check your fiddle i made a update https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/25/

Comment: @ArunpandianM yup, that answers the question, yet i need a bit more than this but its another question tho, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` to transform js object to string.

```
jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
        jQuery("#results").append("<li>" + JSON.stringify(item) + "</li>");
});
```

You should use `item` instead since you have iterate over `data`.

Comment: yup thanks a lot, another comment said that. I will accept the answer as it is correct for my question, yet to resolve the most vast general aim I am trying to achieve, I believe i need another call aftwards :(